# What's the fastest way to remove pyspark columns that are all the same value (e.g. 0)?

Tags: python, performance, filter, pyspark

I have a massive pyspark dataframe and I need to remove any columns from the dataframe that are all 0's.  I'm currently using this code below for this:

```
columns = list(masterdata_raw.schema.names)
zero_col = []
for col_ in columns:
    col_max = masterdata_raw.agg({col_: "max"}).collect()[0]
    col_min = masterdata_raw.agg({col_: "min"}).collect()[0]
    if col_max == 0 and col_min == 0:
        zero_col = zero_col.append(col_)

#*********removing the features found above************
for col_ in zero_col:
    masterdata_raw = masterdata_raw.drop(col_)
```

Unfortunately this runs an aggregation twice and `.collect`'s the results twice as well...SLOW

I tried to combine the aggregations already, but because I was trying to aggregate on the same column name within one dictionary, I only got one result back.  I guess I could have added another column with a different name and then aggregated both at the same time, but that seemed inefficient as well.

What's the fastest way to filter out all of these `0` columns in pyspark?

Comment: what about `describe`?

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
for col_ in columns:
     if masterdata_raw.groupBy().sum(col_).collect() == 0
        masterdata_raw.drop(col_)
```

Comment: this won't necessarily work. (e.g., a column of 50 negative ones and 50 ones)